# What is this shining look like effect called?

Tags: film-techniques, running-scared

In *Running Scared (2005)*, The Scene where Detective Rydell show his badge to Anzor, then this effect is used on his badge:

[image]

What is this shining look like effect called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This effect is **Twitch Effect**, it can be achieved in softwares like Sony Vegas etc.

Sample video:

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't come across well in your image but this is a **stroboscopic** effect.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroboscopic_effect)

It's not clear why it's being used here other than to heighten the tension of seeing the badge on Anzor although it might be a play on "flashing a badge".